# User Defined Annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I am new to user defined annotations. I am trying to create my own annotation like `@NotNull`
annotation.

I want the annotation on method and I want that method to be executed if it satisfies the conditions.

Here is my code:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PolicyCheck{

    String[] policies();    
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
@PolicyCheck(policies = {"P1", "P2"})
public void doSomething(){


}
```

When I call it on a method with the provided policies, if it satisfies the condition, then only it must run the method.

Correct me if I am wrong with the usage of the annotations and please tell if it is possible. Also I am stuck where to write the logic behind it.

Thanks.

Comment: Who calls the method?

Comment: Via reflection you can find out that on which methods you have applied your annotation, Now you have to think what you want to do if somebody calls the same method on which you have applied this annotation?

Comment: You need to make some proxy of the class, when some person calls an annotated method on the proxy object, then you need to decide what actions you want to perform.

Comment: @SAM: thanks for the comment. I am kinda confused here.Could you please explain me with a simple code sample. Sorry to ask but i searched everywhere, but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: @ADi Would you please elaborate your requirement, what you want to do with the custom annotation? I will be more than happy to help you.

Comment: @SAM: I want my own annotation for a method, if applied, it will check the criteria, in my case I want the specific policies to be satisfied before executing that method. Is there any way I can achieve it using user defined annotations or I have to do it externally by creating a method to check the policies each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations can be evaluated at runtime or compile time, what method to choose depends on the actual use case.

At runtime using reflections: As mentioned in the comments, you need a proxy class. You need to intercept any calls to the annotated method, check the policies and then either call the real method or throw an exception for example. Java provides the [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class, which you could to check the permissions inside an [`InvocationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html). You could let the user use dependency injection or provide a method that handles the creation of a proxy.
For example a method like this: `Foo foo = YourAnnotationLibrary.createProxy(Foo.class);`

Another way is to use an [annotation processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) which can be run when the user compiles the code. This is useful for static checks, like assuring certain parameter types on annotated methods - but you won't be able to check for null arguments which occur at runtime. You could generate proxy classes though which will enforce policies at runtime.

Using reflections is probably less complicated. If annotation processing is applicable for your use case, it may be more convenient for the user because it nicely integrates with modern IDEs to show warnings, errors or additional information directly on elements in the source code editor and can prevent many errors before the application is run.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try and implement this.